# Bluetooth connection between Flutter App and Raspberry Pi

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to get the sensor's data (sensor is connected to raspberry pi 4) on Flutter android application using Bluetooth. I am unable to set up connection between raspberry pi and Flutter. Has anyone worked on this before?
Please share if you have any documentation/resources regarding this.
P.S. I tried using flutter_bluetooth_serial library but unable to setup connection.

Comment: You should add your source code so far. Also: flutter_bluetooth_serial is a library for Bluetooth Classic, your question contains the Tag for Bluetooth Low Energy. If you are using BLE you have to use something like https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble

Comment: Did you reach to any thing in this question ?

Comment: @HagerKhaled yes something like this - [link](https://github.com/TinoMeister/flutter_bluetooth_raspberry)